# Scope of a service within Lazy Loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am loading a module lazily in my angular2 project. I understand that the services are singleton and need to be declared globally in order to get the same instance available for lazily loaded modules. But the problem I am facing is that i have a service within the lazy module and is being used in that module only. I don't want this to make a global service. I have configured the service in providers at module level, but all of my components are getting a different instance for the module level service as well. Can somebody please explain the behavior.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    SharedModule,
    route
],
providers: [LazyModuleService],
declarations: [AComponent, BComponent]
```

})

Both A and B component are getting separate instances of `LazyModuleService`

Comment: I think that shouldn't be the expected behavior, how do you know they are separate instances?

Comment: Printed the object codes and they gave different references

Comment: Hmm, never tried testing it that way, I always add a console.log to the service's constructor and see if it's logged more than once, can you try that?

Comment: I tried logging in constructor as well. it prints twice

Comment: That's weird, could you create a plunk maybe?

Comment: Find the plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/shOEKUXxbExpHKapxaDh?p=preview visit crisit center and then go to any one of these 1 - Dragon Burning Cities
2 - Sky Rains Great White Sharks
3 - Giant Asteroid Heading For Earth
4 - Procrastinators Meeting Delayed Again

See the console, service is created again

Comment: I'm seeing the issue, it is weird, but by the way, I wouldn't create a module entirely for routing, that's exactly what the RouterModule.forRoot/forChild reutrns - a module, just create the route array and skip the module with only RouterModule in it. (Tested - this does not fix it, still looking)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136935/discussion-between-amit-dahan-and-sumit-agarwal).